# Por que o segundo estilo que defini para a tag P não sobrepõem o primeiro?

Tags: css, aplicação-web, front-end, seletores

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div p.center {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  background:orange;
}
p.center {
  text-align: end;
  color: blue;
  background:pink;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="center">This heading will not be affected</h1>
<div>
  <p class="center">This paragraph will be red and center-aligned.</p> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```